# What does the notation $\mathbf{1}_{\{i=l\}}$ mean?

Tags: notation, scientific-notation

I found this notation in a published article, with no formal definition. I am attaching a screenshot of where it's used.

[image]

[image]

where, $i,l \in \mathcal{N}$.

I am guessing $\mathbf{1}_{\{i=l\}}$ denotes a vector of all zeroes, except a one at index $i=l$. This is because $\frac{\partial S_i}{\partial P_l}$ would be $1$ for $i=l$ (as per the equation), while $0$ otherwise. Is this correct?

Comment: The [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $\mathbb{1}_{A}(x) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in A\\0&\text{if }x\not\in A\end{cases}$.  In your case, it is equal to $1$ if $i=l$ and equal to $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).